# Delete Folder from gitHub through eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, git

I have made a project in eclipse and have committed it to github.

Now i have switched my project from eclipse to android studio.

I don't have access to delete the project from github so I have made a new folder in Github.

Now i want to remove the old folder in which I have my eclipse project.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: By folder do you mean a repository ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any IDEs to make it, just use git cli.
For example:

```
cd <project-dir>
rm -rf <folder_deleted>
git add --all
git commit -m "delete the folder.^_^"
git push
```

It's done!

Comment: I think Github requires credentials, so if he can't do it by website, he will not do that either

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete repo form Github, you need credentials anyway, no matter if you will try to do that from colmmand line or Github.